# jquery agregar parametro a varios links, sin perder el href original

Tags: jquery

Quiero agregar un parámetro tipo `?lang=en` al atributo `href` de todos los links que tengan la clase `tradulink`, el problema es que no logro conservar el `href` original de cada link, o sea lo que quiero es que se sume el valor conservando cada `href` original, ejemplo `index.html?lang=en` o `contacto.html?lang=en` (ahora me pasa que toma la URL actual y lo aplica a todos los `tradulink`)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("en") != -1) {
        console.log("esta en ingles");
    }

    //cuando cliqueo el boton #goen:
    $('#goen').click (function(){
        // renueva el contenido
        $('.en').css('visibility','visible');
        $('.es, .por').css('visibility','hidden');

        //agrega parametro ?lang=en a los links con la clase "tradulink"
        //var url = window.location.href;
        $('.tradulink').attr("href", "?lang=en");
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar el `attr` de cada elemento en una variable y asignarle como nuevo `attr` el valor guardado concatenando la parte `string` que deseas agregar:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#goen').click (function(){      
      $.each($('.tradulink'), function(index, dato){
         var attr = $(dato).attr("href").split('?')[0];
          $(dato).attr("href", attr+ "?lang=en");
          
          console.log($(dato).attr("href"));
      });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com" >Google</a>
<a class="tradulink" href="https://www.facebook.com" >Facebook</a>
<a class="tradulink" href="https://www.instagram.com" >Instagram</a>

<button id="goen">Botón</button>
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionó, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ojo, que si seleccionas nuevamente el boton de cambiar sumara a tu direccion de la siguiente manera: url?lang=en?lang=en ...

Comment: yo pensaría que la función la ejecutaras una sola vez cuando **cargue la página** y no desde un **boton**

Comment: @jolsalazar tienes razón no había pensado en eso, ya corregí el código para que no pase

Comment: Pero estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila

Comment: Justo estaba peleando con ese tema, y estaba por volver a preguntar. Realmente les agradezco mucho!!

Answer (score 1):

Con este codigo puedes agregarle un parametro a los enlaces de tu pagina.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

if (window.location.href.indexOf("en") != -1) {
    console.log("esta en ingles");
}

  //cuando cliqueo el boton #goen:
  $('#goen').click (function(){
      var enlaceActual = '';
      $('.tradulink').each(function(i, anchor){
        enlaceActual = $(anchor).attr("href").split('?')[0];
        $(anchor).attr("href", enlaceActual + "?lang=en");
      });
  })
  
  $('#goes').click (function(){
      var enlaceActual = '';
      $('.tradulink').each(function(i, anchor){
        enlaceActual = $(anchor).attr("href").split('?')[0];
        $(anchor).attr("href", enlaceActual + "?lang=es");
      });
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript:;" id="goen">Solo ingles</a><br>
<a href="javascript:;" id="goes">Solo español</a><br>

<hr>
<a href="http://www.misitio.com" class="tradulink" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.misitio2.com" class="tradulink" target="_blank">Link2</a>
```

Espero te pueda servir,
Saludos.

Comment: Con este codigo estas eliminando el parametro anterior antes de sumar el nuevo, no?

Comment: Estoy "limpiando" cualquier parametro despues del "?" de la URL

Comment: Muchas gracias !!